# derive formula for height of tower on a hill

Tags: trigonometry

I'm working through a book to learn trig on my own and I got stuck with the following.  This is the image given and the text in the book reads:

> Suppose you are standing an unknown distance away from a cliff of height $h$.  You need to know the height $t$ of a tower located on top of the cliff.   You know that the angle of elevation of the bottom of the tower is $B$ and the angle of elevation of the top of the tower is $A$.  Derive a formula for the height of the tower.

[image]

The solution they gave is $t = h\left({{tan A}\over{tan B}}-1\right)$.  I don't quite understand how to derive that answer. I think that the height is going to be $d(tanA - tanB)$ where $d$ is the unknown adjacent side. I get stuck after that.  The more verbose the answer the better.  Thanks!

Comment: Note: your answer is in terms of $A,B$, and $d$, while theirs is in terms of $A,B$, and $h$.  They may be both right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the distance to the hill $d$.

Then $\tan B = \frac{h}{d}$ and $\tan A = \frac{h+t}{d}.$

Eliminating $d$ gives the desired result:

$$\frac{h}{\tan B} = \frac{h+t}{\tan A}$$

$$\frac{h}{\tan B} = \frac{h}{\tan A}+ \frac{t}{\tan A}$$

$$\frac{t}{\tan A} = \frac{h}{\tan B} - \frac{h}{\tan A}$$

$$t = (\tan A)\left(\frac{h}{\tan B} - \frac{h}{\tan A}\right)$$

$$t = h(\tan A)\left(\frac{1}{\tan B} - \frac{1}{\tan A}\right)$$

$$t = h\left(\frac{\tan A}{\tan B} - \frac{\tan A}{\tan A}\right)$$

$$t = h\left(\frac{\tan A}{\tan B} - 1\right).$$

Comment: I don't understand how you're pulling out the $t$.  I tried cross multiplying and distributing the $tanA$ across the $(h+t)$ but I'm missing some step.

Comment: I added the part that pulls the $t$ out into its own fraction. Does that help?

Comment: I understand how you pulled it into its own fraction but then you  jump to the final expression and I'm not sure of the steps that you used to get there.

Comment: Straight algebra.  I added the intermediate steps.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I didn't understand when $h$ was pulled out and a 1 placed in its place.   Thanks again!

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

We have $$\tan A=\frac{t+h}d\iff d=\frac{t+h}{\tan A}$$

Similarly, $$\tan B=\frac hd\iff d=\frac h{\tan B}$$

Compare the two values of $d$